# Java Spring: "no main manifest attribute" when executing .jar

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, jar

I've made a little API using SpringBoot with Java and Gradle. I'm using InteliJ and i've followed their documentation to compile my app in an executable .jar : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#run_packaged_jar

The problem is that when I execute my .jar via the InteliJ IDE or via the command line, Java returns me this error :

```
no main manifest attribute, in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\api\out\artifacts\api_jar\api.jar

Process finished with exit code 1
```

...which is pretty weird considering I have made a .MANIFEST file in my project :

MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.sharelink.api.SharelinkApiApplication
```

Do you know if there is something wrong with my MANIFEST file? Maybe its the way I compile my .jar ? I really don't know and I didnt find anything online that could help me with this issue....

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have a look inside your jar file and see what's in the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Also, check the guide here to see if it helps by using the `mvn clean package` to package it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-fix-the-no-main-manifest-attribute

Comment: (1) Please use `https://start.spring.io/` to create a springboot apllication , then generated a  demo.zip (2) unzip demo.zip (3) `cd demo` , `gradle clean build` (4) if error , you can delete `src/test`, rerun `gradle clean build`(5) `cd  build/libs`, you can find `demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` then run `java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, (6) if everything is ok, you can ise IDEA open this project. (7) you don't need build  `MANIFEST.MF` your self (if you use plugin org.springframework.boot)